# Xamarin Grid RowSpan/ColSpan Not Stretching

Tags: xamarin, html-table, grid

I have a 5x5 grid defined with column definitions and row definitions. The first column contains 5 rows of entry boxes in a frame. The second column is to contain a custom view I created which itself made up of a grid that contains two graphs side by side, rotated 90 degrees.

The problem I am having is even though I am setting, the colspan, rowspan, widthRequest, heightRequest, horizontal and vertical options on the custom view, I am unable to get the view to stretch the entire length of the first column.

My grid code:

```
`<Grid x:Name="Grid">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" OutlineColor="Black" Padding="1" BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="40" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Entry WidthRequest="10"  
                                   BackgroundColor="Blue" 
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"  
                                   Focused="entryFocused" 
                                   Unfocused="entryUnfocused" 
                                   Completed="entryComplete"
                                   Keyboard="Numeric"/>
                </Frame>
                <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" OutlineColor="Black" Padding="1" BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="40" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Entry WidthRequest="10"  
                                   BackgroundColor="Blue" 
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"  
                                   Focused="entryFocused" 
                                   Unfocused="entryUnfocused" 
                                   Completed="entryComplete"
                                   Keyboard="Numeric"/>
                </Frame>
                <Frame Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" OutlineColor="Black" Padding="1" BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="40" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Entry WidthRequest="10"  
                                   BackgroundColor="Blue" 
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"  
                                   Focused="entryFocused" 
                                   Unfocused="entryUnfocused" 
                                   Completed="entryComplete"
                                   Keyboard="Numeric"/>
                </Frame>
                <Frame Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" OutlineColor="Black" Padding="1" BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="40" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Entry WidthRequest="10"  
                                   BackgroundColor="Blue" 
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"  
                                   Focused="entryFocused" 
                                   Unfocused="entryUnfocused" 
                                   Completed="entryComplete"
                                   Keyboard="Numeric"/>
                </Frame>
                <Frame Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" OutlineColor="Black" Padding="1" BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="40" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Entry WidthRequest="10"  
                                   BackgroundColor="Blue" 
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"  
                                   Focused="entryFocused" 
                                   Unfocused="entryUnfocused" 
                                   Completed="entryComplete"
                                   Keyboard="Numeric"/>
                </Frame>
                <custom:BoardMeasureGraph_Micro x:Name="Micro" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.RowSpan="1"  Margin="150, 80, 0, 0"  MinimumHeightRequest="430" MinimumWidthRequest="475" HeightRequest="400" WidthRequest="400" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
            </Grid>`
```

My custom view code :

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <Grid Padding="0" RowSpacing="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" ColumnSpacing="0" Rotation="90" TranslationX="-149" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <microcharts:ChartView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ChartView" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="150" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  />
        <microcharts:ChartView Grid.Row="1" Rotation="180" RotationY="180"  x:Name="UnderChartView" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  />
    </Grid>
</ContentView.Content>
```

[image: The output when running the App. The custom control never expands beyond the first couple of entry boxes.]

The output when running the App. The custom control never expands beyond the first couple of entry boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set colSpan to 4 instead of 5, since you want it to cover 4 columns (1,2,3,4 - not 0).

```
<custom:BoardMeasureGraph_Micro x:Name="Micro" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="1"  Margin="150, 80, 0, 0"  MinimumHeightRequest="430" MinimumWidthRequest="475" HeightRequest="400" WidthRequest="400" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

Also I am not sure if it is possible to combine height/width Requests with the grid configuration. Maybe this causes some issue too. But as I said, I am not sure about this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it but it didn't work. There's something about the grid and the fact that its rotated that seems to be messing it up. I've tried various values for the colspan and rowspan with no avail. I think I will try an AbsoluteLayout and see if I have better luck.